# Data profiling on complete data in DataPrep

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I need to do data profiling on complete dataset in Dataprep. I also wanted to confirm if data profiling in Dataprep is done on sample data or complete data which we have?

Answer (score 0):

- Profiling in the UI is only done over the sample data which is loaded in the transformer interface.
- During job execution, profiling is executed across the **entire dataset**.

See [Overview of profiling](https://docs.trifacta.com/display/DP/Profiling+Basics) or [Overview+of+Visual+Profiling](https://docs.trifacta.com/display/DP/Overview+of+Visual+Profiling#:%7E:text=During%20job%20execution%2C%20it%20is%20queried%20as%20a%20separate%20job%20when%20profiling%20is%20executed%20across%20the%20entire%20dataset).